# How can I add a hook in the AndroidManifest.xml for Firebase to initialize?

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics

I've been using Firebase for a few things already, but now I want to add the Crashlytics and on step 3 in the guide it is said "For Android apps, a hook in the AndroidManifest.xml file automatically initializes the Firebase SDK."

Is there something I actually need to do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, the documentation is saying that the hook already exists, if you use the default integration steps for Firebase.  It's a ContentProvider that gets merged into the app by the build system.  This ContentProvided is loaded first thing when the app starts, and its sole purpose is to initialize the Firebase SDK.